# How can I connect to wpa wifi access point from a freashly loaded SystemRescueCd?

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, gentoo

There are many wifi access points around me which passwords I know. I try to install gentoo linux from SystemRescueCd. It supports wpa. How I can scan for access points in the console? How I can connect to an access point from the shell?

Comment: Might help - http://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-938182-start-0.html

Comment: Seems like solution.

Comment: Did it solve the problem?

Comment: I can try it this evening.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do it from SysRescueCD's shell, but if you use `startx` then you can easily use the *Network manager* icon in the lower right of the screen, just left of the date-and-time and virtual-screens.